# Server Not Found

Tags: connection

I am kinda happy that my Tor hidden service is/was running.

So after i turned off the PC, i decided to search my website on Tor Browser (on mobile phone), and the result said "Server not found"

**Question**
-What might have gone wrong? 
-Would it be a must, for my PC and Tor service running on ubuntu, before my website could be found on the Tor Browser?

Answer (score 1):

The computer running your hidden service must be running for it to be accessible. Small single-board computers like a Raspberry Pi are a relatively inexpensive way to run an always-on service (but they can't handle a lot of traffic at once). If you aren't worried about anonymity, some people also run their hidden service on a VPS which is much simpler to configure.

Answer (score 0):

Tor is not like ZeroNet or IPFS, so when you're connecting to a hidden service  - basically you're connecting to the server that is *running* a service, i.e. there's no offline cache like CloudFlare, even if your website is a fully static one. You **have** to keep your server running to access it either directly or through Tor. If you have a fully static site and you need it to be online while your server is not - just migrate to the ZeroNet, it's the right spot to be for you in this case.